# Save a chart into a different Excel sheet

Tags: matlab, charts, insert, excel-formula

This is what I need to do:

- 1) Open an existing Excel file using Matlab
- 2) Write data to the excel file using Matlab (currently using xlswrite1)
- 3) Insert a chart into an already existing sheet in the excel file that I specify

I got #1 and #2 working, but I'm stuck on #3.

The things I have tried for #3 either put it in a separate new sheet (even when I specify the active sheet) or puts it in the correct sheet, but I somehow lose the handles to the chart and can't assign `ChartType` without getting an error.

Comment: are you working on Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code provided by Mathworks Support Team (link provided below) for inserting MATLAB Figure in an Excel sheet. You might have to update the sheet to your intended one.

```
% Create sample image from figure

img = 'figure1.png';

plot(1:10);

print('-dpng', img);

% Get handle to Excel COM Server

Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');

% Set it to visible 

set(Excel,'Visible',1);

% Add a Workbook

Workbooks = Excel.Workbooks;

Workbook = invoke(Workbooks, 'Add');

% Get a handle to Sheets and select Sheet 1

Sheets = Excel.ActiveWorkBook.Sheets;

Sheet1 = get(Sheets, 'Item', 1);

Sheet1.Activate;

% Alternative 1 BEGIN.

% Get a handle to Shapes for Sheet 1

Shapes = Sheet1.Shapes;

% Add image

Shapes.AddPicture([pwd '\' img] ,0,1,400,18,300,235);

% Alternative 1 END.

% Alternative 2 BEGIN.

% Add image

Sheet1.invoke('Pictures').Insert([pwd '\' img]);

% Alternative 2 END.

% Save the workbook and Close Excel

invoke(Workbook, 'SaveAs', [pwd '\myfile.xls']);

invoke(Excel, 'Quit');

% In the above code (Alternative 1), Excel's Shapes.AddPicture Method is used to insert a figure in the Excel Sheet - Mathworks.
```

[Link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/91547-how-do-i-insert-a-matlab-figure-into-an-excel-workbook-through-activex) to the response above:

A function `img2xlsx` by H K.Berg - which transfers one or multiple image(s) to a new or existing xlsx-file) can be [downloaded](http://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/51191-img2xlsx) from MATLAB Central

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. And solution 2 is not actually what I was trying to do. I wanted to create an Excel figure in Excel from MATLAB not just insert a MATLAB figure into Excel.

This is what I ended up using:
Excel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
Workbook = invoke(Excel.Workbooks,'Open',fullfilename);
resultsheet = name;
sheet = get(Excel.Worksheets,'Item', resultsheet);
invoke(sheet, 'Activate'); 
Chart = Excel.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2; 

The activate sheet command does not seem to work with the invoke chart command.